# PHP redirect recent page

Tags: php, codeigniter

i enter data from modal, and the form action is on controller, i want to make a alert if it true / not the data with session. like this,

```
$rules = [
            'required'  => [
                ['name'],['description']
            ]
        ];

        $validate   = Validation::check($rules,'post');

if(!$validate->auth){
            $this->session->set_userdata('error', 'error!');
                redirect('recentpagegoeshere');
            }
```

how to redirect to recent page, i cannot use  `header('location:...')` or `redirect('to controller')` because the page is based on recent location

Comment: What do you mean by _"because the page is based on recent location"_ in your last sentence?

Comment: @Mikey the form is on template.blade.php (footer section) so user can input the data everywhere on the web because it's on template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out the answer

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you can redirect with js solution:

```
echo '<script>window.location="http://your-url-here"</script>';
```

You can try to use an html tag too:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=your-url-here">';
```

Comment: i cannot use this because i dont know where "URL" is. because the url is based on recent page